# Relating intersection product $D \cdot \mathcal{F}$ with $D \cdot Y$, where $Y = \operatorname{supp} \mathcal{F}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be smooth variety of dimension $\operatorname{dim} X = d$, let $\mathcal{F} \in \operatorname{Coh}(X)$ be a sheaf supported on a subvariety $Y \subset X$ of codimension $\operatorname{codim}(Y, X) = 1$, and let $D$ be a divisor. How do the intersection products
$$ D \cdot Y \text{ and } D \cdot \mathcal{F}$$
relate? More generally, if $\mathcal{F}$ is supported in dimension $r$, we can consider
$$ D_1 \dotsm D_r \cdot \operatorname{supp}(F) \text{ and } D_1 \dotsm D_r \cdot \mathcal{F}.$$
In *Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry*, Debarre writes

> [...] we may also define an intersection number $$D_1 \dots D_r \cdot \mathcal{F}$$ [...] but this apparently greater generality is illusory.

Unfortunately, he does not expand on this.

Some context: Suppose $X$ is a surface, $\mathcal{F}$ is supported on a curve $C$, and $D$ is an ample divisor. Then I want to conclude
$$D \cdot \mathcal{F} > 0.$$
I know by the Nakai-Moishezon criterion, that
$$ D \cdot C > 0,$$
but I don't know how to relate this to $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: See Kollár, _Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties_, Appendix VI.2 Proposition 2.7. The point is that $D_1 \dotsm D_r \cdot \mathcal{F} = \sum_i l_i (D_1 \dotsm D_r \cdot Y_i )$ where the $Y_i$ are the $r$-dimensional irreducible components of the support of the sheaf and $l_i$ is the length of $F$ at the generic point of $Y_i$.